# Powershell Microsoft API get members of eligible roles

Tags: azure, powershell, permissions, roles, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to get all the members of a role (both active assignments and eligible assignments) but i always recive only the active assignments.

the uri that I used is: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/{RoleID}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryRoles/%7BRoleID%7D/members)

the API permissions that I have are:

````
AdministrativeUnit.ReadWrite.All
Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.Read.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Group.ReadWrite.All
GroupMember.ReadWrite.All
RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory
User.ReadWrite.All
User.Read
UserAuthenticationMethod.ReadWrite.All
Application.ReadWrite.All```
````

Comment: Add the code you have been trying. Tell us what worked/didn't work and if you encountered error messages show these too.

Comment: Can you try this: GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments/roleID/members

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the members of a role assignment (active and eligible) for a directory provider, you can use the below Graph API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//roleManagement/directory/roleAssignments/{id}
```

If you want to get the members of a role assignment (active and eligible) for an entitlement management provider, you can use the below Graph API call:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta//roleManagement/entitlementManagement/roleAssignments/{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this request:

`GET /roleManagement/directory/roleEligibilityScheduleRequests/{unifiedRoleEligibilityScheduleRequestId}`

MS docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/unifiedroleeligibilityschedulerequest-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http